# Why checkout step not recorded in the Google Analytics report?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce, gtag.js

I'm making an enhanched ecommerce tracking with google analytics. I'm following the existing implementation in gtag.js. I have 4 checkout steps including shipping method data, payment method data, pending payment, and also paid (purchase). I've made the codes for each step below:

**1. Shipping Method**

```
<script>
    gtag('event', 'set_checkout_option', {
        "checkout_step": 1,
        "checkout_option": "shipping method",
        "value": ""
    });
</script>
```

**2. Payment Method**

```
<script>
    gtag('event', 'set_checkout_option', {
        "checkout_step": 2,
        "checkout_option": "payment method",
        "value": ""
    });
</script>
```

**3. Pending Payment**

```
$("#order-now-action").on('click', function() {
    gtag('event', 'set_checkout_option', {
        "checkout_step": 3,
        "checkout_option": "pending",
        "id": ""
    });
})
```

This is the checkout funnel that I created in Ecommerce Settings. enter image description here
[image]
And this is a report in the checkout behavior menu. The shipping method is recorded, but why in step 2 (payment method) to step 4 (purchase) is it not recorded? enter image description here
[image]
even though, in the sales performance menu, the transaction is recorded? enter image description here
[image]
for steps 1-3 is in 1 page, while the purchase (step 4) I did on the backend using a single url. Is it because it's on 1 page so it's not recorded?

Comment: Since you already asked this over at Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69766923/why-checkout-step-not-recorded-in-the-google-analytics-report), it's really best to flag it there for migration to another site, or delete it there after posting on another site like this one. [Cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que) questions to different Stack Exchange sites are really not condoned since that spreads answers out among them.

Comment: Sorry, cause I'm new in this webmaster forum @dan

Comment: No worries, welcome to the site btw. I'd recommend deleting it on Stack Overflow since it's not specifically about programming and is a better fit for this site. Perhaps someone will come along and give you some help here - good luck!